# How can I call a class variable from a callback function?

Tags: java, this

I have a class that has this structure:

```
public class MyClass {

    private double myDouble;
    private MyObject myObject;

    public myMethod() {

        AnotherObject anotherObject = new AnotherObject();        
        anotherObject.getInfo(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void success(MyObject myObject) {
                this.myObject = myObject; // this is what I would like to do
            }

            // and a method for the failure case
        });

    }
}
```

Essentially, I am looking for a way to save the value of `myObject` that I get from the `success` method inside the instance variable `myObject` (`this.myObject`). Currently, with the above code, I get a "Cannot resolve symbol 'myObject'" message.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try that? What errors did you get?

Comment: @Tunaki uhm, yeah... I get "cannot resolve symbol 'myObject'". I'll update the question.

Comment: Two ways: either `MyClass.this.myObject"; or much easier: simply avoid that the success method parameter shadows that name in the first place. Change the parameter name to "incomingObject"; and then myObject = incomingObject works fine.

Comment: And side note. I assume this is just example code, but MyClass, myObject and so on are pretty pure names for classes and variables ..

Comment: @Jägermeister your assumption is correct :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close, since you are within an inner class you have to prefix `this` with a little extra information:

```
MyClass.this.myObject = myObject;
```

Otherwise `this` refers to the anonymous `Callback` class you are defining.

Comment: You probably mean "since you are within an inner class"

Comment: Anonymous class is probably more correct, edited my answer.

Comment: Not really. If the class was a named inner class (i.e. not anonymous), the OP would have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While now I can call the class variable, do you have any idea why I might get a `null` value outside the callback? If I output the value of `MyClass.this.myObject` inside `success`, after the assignment, I get the correct value, but if I do it within `myMethod`, I get `null`

Comment: Your callback likely hasn't called back yet, you could call a separate method call within `success` to ensure myObject has been set before you try to manipulate it further.

Comment: I opened another question since it's a different issue altogether, if you want to have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35961591/object-becomes-null-outside-of-callback-function/35961668#35961668