# Object becomes null outside of callback function

Tags: java, android

I have a callback function whose result I save in a class variable, like this:

```
public class MyClass {

    private double myDouble;
    private MyObject myObject;

    public myMethod() {

        AnotherObject anotherObject = new AnotherObject();        
        anotherObject.getInfo(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void success(MyObject myObject) {
                MyClass.this.myObject = myObject; // I save myObject inside the class variable myObject
                Log.d("LOG", "Value of myObject " + MyClass.this.myObject);

            }

            // a method for the failure case
        });
        Log.d("LOG", "Value of myObject " + MyClass.this.myObject);

    }
}
```

The first log message gives me the correct value, by which I suppose that the class variable `myObject` correctly stored the object value. However, the second log message, right outside the `success` function, returns `null`.

How can I get the correct object value also outside the callback function?

Comment: Your code prints `null` for the "second" `Log.d` because it is actually executed "first", so it doesn't "become null"; it was already `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assuming that the callback passed to getInfo() will be executed *immediately* upon its return.  Given your observed behavior, that is not the case.  The callback is actually being invoked some time *after* getInfo() returns.

Sometimes callbacks are called immediately, but in this case not.  Many callbacks are invoked by work done in another thread, and in those cases, the thread invoking getInfo() is simply continuing on while the other thread does some computation.  When you have a callback like that that is not guaranteed to be invoked immediately, you should only refer to its results in the callback itself, or some time after the callback is invoked.

Answer (score 6):

This is a callback, i.e. asynchronous in nature. You can't know when the `success()` method will be called and the assignment to `myObject` probably happens after checking it's value. Make sure you call `Log.d()` after the callback has completed.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the variable public static

```
public static MyObject myObject
```

and using it as

```
MyClass.myObject = something; //assign the data
```

Comment: Sorry, same behavior after making the variable static

Comment: And you are accessing it like this "MyClass.myObject"? and try renaming the variable to something else.

Comment: Yes, `MyClass.myObject`. After renaming it, still `null`

Comment: Callbacks are asynchronous. Adding static doesn't do anything